# Failed to build report with image at Java application: "Byte data not found at some_path"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jasper-reports

Is it possible to use jrxml file directly to generate pdf using Java Jasper API when java web application is delpoyed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here I am storing "empprofile.jrxml" file in "WEB-INF/reports" directory. Report successfully generates when I deploy application on localhost. But it does not generate pdf when deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Please give any sugessions to solve this issue.
Below is the code I have used to generate pdf:

```
package controller;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import bean.AppointmentBean;
import bean.EducationBean;
import bean.EmployeeAddressBean;
import bean.EmployeeBankBean;
import bean.EmployeeBean;
import bean.EmployeePersonalBean;
import bean.KnEmployeeBean;
import bean.KrudnyataListBean;
import bean.PayscaleBean;
import bean.RelativeBean;
import bean.ServiceHistoryBean;
import dao.AppointmentDao;
import dao.EducationalDao;
import dao.EmployeeDao;
import dao.PayscaleDao;
import dao.RelativeDao;
import dao.krudnyatanidhi.KrudnyataNidhiDao;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;

public class PrintProfile extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PrintProfile() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
        try{
            if(session.getAttribute("category")!=null)
            {
                if(session.getAttribute("category").equals("admin")||session.getAttribute("category").equals("badmin")){
                    try{
                        String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
                        EmployeeDao dao=new EmployeeDao();
                        EmployeeBean bean=dao.getEmployeeBeanByUID(uid);
                        request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
                        session.setAttribute("uid", uid);
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("printprofile.jsp").forward(request, response);

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    session=request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute("category", null);
                    response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
                }
            }
            else{
                session=request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("category", null);
                response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            session=request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("category", null);
            response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
        try{
            if(session.getAttribute("category")!=null)
            {
                if(session.getAttribute("category").equals("admin")||session.getAttribute("category").equals("badmin")){
                    try{
                        String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
                        String personal=request.getParameter("personal");
                        String address=request.getParameter("address");
                        String bank=request.getParameter("bank");
                        String appt=request.getParameter("appt");
                        String educational=request.getParameter("educational");
                        String serviceh=request.getParameter("serviceh");
                        String payscale=request.getParameter("payscale");
                        String krudnyatanidhi=request.getParameter("krudnyatanidhi");
                        String relative=request.getParameter("relative");
                        String date=request.getParameter("today");

                        EmployeePersonalBean pbean=null;
                        EmployeeBankBean empbank=null;
                        EmployeeAddressBean empaddress=null;
                        AppointmentBean empappt=null;
                        ArrayList<EducationBean> qualsds=null;
                        ArrayList<PayscaleBean> archives=null;
                        ArrayList<RelativeBean> relatives=null;
                        ArrayList<ServiceHistoryBean> sh=null;
                        KrudnyataListBean knstatus=null;
                        ArrayList<KnEmployeeBean> knlist=new ArrayList<>();

                        EmployeeDao dao=new EmployeeDao();
                        EmployeeBean bean=dao.getEmployeeBeanByUID(uid);

                        if(personal!=null){
                            pbean=dao.getEmpPersonal(uid);
                        }

                        if(bank!=null){
                            empbank=dao.getEmpBank(uid);
                        }

                        if(address!=null){
                            empaddress=dao.getEmpAddress(uid);
                        }


                        InputStream photo=dao.getEmployeePhoto(uid);
                        if(photo==null){
                            String directoryPath=getServletContext().getRealPath("images");
                            File image=new File(directoryPath+File.separator+"pna.png");
                            photo=new FileInputStream(image);
                        }
                        AppointmentDao adao=new AppointmentDao();


                        empappt=adao.getAppointmentDetailsForReport(uid);




                        EducationalDao eDao=new EducationalDao();

                        if(educational!=null){
                            qualsds=eDao.getEducationalDetails(uid);
                        }

                        JRBeanCollectionDataSource quals=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(qualsds);

                        PayscaleDao pdao=new PayscaleDao();

                        if(payscale!=null){
                            archives=pdao.getPayscaleArchives(uid);
                        }

                        JRBeanCollectionDataSource payscalearchive=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(archives);

                        RelativeDao rDao=new RelativeDao();

                        if(relative!=null){
                            relatives=rDao.getRelativesDetails(uid);
                        }

                        JRBeanCollectionDataSource relativeds=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(relatives);

                        if(serviceh!=null){
                            sh=adao.getBranchHReport(uid);
                        }

                        JRBeanCollectionDataSource servicehistoryds=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(sh);

                        KrudnyataNidhiDao kdao=new KrudnyataNidhiDao();
                        Double totalpaid=0.0;
                        if(krudnyatanidhi!=null){
                            knlist=kdao.getKNListEmployeewiseForReport(uid);
                            /*for (KrudnyataPaymentBean b: paymenthistory) {
                                totalpaid=totalpaid+b.getAmount();
                            }*/
                        }

                        JRBeanCollectionDataSource krpds=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(knlist);

                        //Report Generation Code

                        String imgContext=this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

                        Map<String,Object> parameterMap=new HashMap<String,Object>();
                        parameterMap.put("uid",uid);
                        parameterMap.put("context",imgContext);
                        parameterMap.put("personal",personal);
                        parameterMap.put("address",address);
                        parameterMap.put("bank",bank);
                        parameterMap.put("appt",appt);
                        parameterMap.put("educational",educational);
                        parameterMap.put("serviceh",serviceh);
                        parameterMap.put("payscale",payscale);
                        parameterMap.put("krudnyatanidhi",krudnyatanidhi);
                        parameterMap.put("relative",relative);
                        parameterMap.put("bean",bean);
                        parameterMap.put("pbean",pbean);
                        parameterMap.put("empbank",empbank);
                        parameterMap.put("empaddress",empaddress);
                        parameterMap.put("photo",photo);
                        parameterMap.put("empappt",empappt);
                        parameterMap.put("date",date);
                        parameterMap.put("quals",quals);
                        parameterMap.put("payscalearchive",payscalearchive);
                        parameterMap.put("relativeds",relativeds);
                        parameterMap.put("knstatus",knstatus);
                        parameterMap.put("krpds",krpds);
                        parameterMap.put("totalpaid",totalpaid);
                        parameterMap.put("servicehistoryds",servicehistoryds);



                        OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
                        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                        /*Connection con=DBConnection.createconnection();*/
                        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
                        String report = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/empprofile.jrxml");
                        JasperReport jasperReport = null;
                        JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
                        try {
                            jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(report);
                            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
                            byte[] byteStream = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport,parameterMap,new JREmptyDataSource());
                            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                            response.setContentType("application/pdf");

                            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",bean.getUid()+"-"+bean.getFname()+" "+bean.getLname()+".pdf");
                            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
                            response.setContentLength(byteStream.length);
                            outStream.write(byteStream,0,byteStream.length); 
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    session=request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute("category", null);
                    response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
                }
            }
            else{
                session=request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("category", null);
                response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            session=request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("category", null);
            response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp?success=0");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part of AWS log  of catalina.out file :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF\reports\pdealogo.png
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytes(RepositoryUtil.java:206)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(JRImageRenderer.java:141)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:441)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.evaluate(JRFillFrame.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:468)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:327)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:903)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:832)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:421)
    at controller.PrintProfile.doPost(PrintProfile.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad. `But it does not generate pdf when deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.` - What does it mean?

Comment: I am deploying web application on AWS and after deploying web application, pdf was unable to generate.

Comment: Pdf is successfully generated when web application deployed on localhost

Comment: `pdf was unable to generate` - Do you have some error?

Comment: Actually I don't have access to AWS Console...I am requesting AWS error logs to our server administrator and after getting that I will let you know....Thanks

Comment: I am using some image like "pdealogo.png" in this report and images are stored in WEB-INF/reports directory...On localhost it takes right context path but on AWS it searches for that images at "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF\reports\pdealogo.png" this path which is invalid...

Comment: Duplicates: [how to display image in jasper reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10976318/876298) & [JasperReports API. Getting error when using Image in report: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36457059/876298) & [How to set the image expression to always store the right image path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40840413/876298) & [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27174786/876298)

Comment: Thanks Alex K for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution. I have checked the catalina.out log file from AWS server logs. It contains the exceptions occured as shown below:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF\reports\pdealogo.png
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytes(RepositoryUtil.java:206)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance(JRImageRenderer.java:141)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:498)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:441)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillFrame.evaluate(JRFillFrame.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:468)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:327)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:903)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:832)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:421)
    at controller.PrintProfile.doPost(PrintProfile.java:236)
```

So the problem was I am developing my web application on Windows and deploying it on Linux server so basically it was the issue of writing path for linux system. I have changed Image Path in jrxml file as shown below:

Old Path:

```
<imageExpression>
   <![CDATA[$P{context}.toString()+"WEB-INF\\reports\\pdealogo.png"]]>
</imageExpression>
```

New Path:

```
<imageExpression>
   <![CDATA[$P{context}.toString()+"WEB-INF/reports/pdealogo.png"]]>
</imageExpression>
```